# How to plot arrows on map in R with ggmap

Tags: r, google-maps, plot, ggmap

I am trying to make a geographical plot in R with points of various airports, and then arrows between them, indicating a particular flight route.

According to some earlier questions here on stack overflow, this should be possible using ggmap and geom_segment, but it seems like it wont work using the approach i have in my code below:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(ggmap)


#=============================== Data ===============================#  


#Retrieving coordinates for two airports
Adress = c("Lufthavnsboulevarden 6, 2770 Kastrup, Denmark", "Edvard Munchs veg, 2061 Gardermoen, Norway")

# This function geocodes a location (find latitude and longitude) using the Google Maps API
geo <- geocode(location = Adress, output="latlon", source="google")

#moving the data around, so that second observation will be end-destination
geo$lonend[1] <- geo$lon[2]
geo$latend[1] <- geo$lat[2]

#removing second row
row_to_keep = c(TRUE, FALSE)
geo = geo[row_to_keep,]

#putting a number in there to make some dots for the airports
geo$Number = 999

#=============================== Ploting =============================# 

# get a Google map
require(ggmap)
map<-get_map(location='Europe', zoom=5, maptype = "terrain",
             source='google',color='color')

# plot it with ggplot2
require("ggplot2")
require("RColorBrewer")
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(
    aes(x=lon, 
        y=lat, 
        show_guide = TRUE, 
        colour=Number), 
    data=geo, 
    alpha=.8, 
    na.rm = T)  + 
  scale_color_gradient(low="beige", high="blue")

#Set the pointer from (y,x) => (yend,xend) using geom-segment
ggmap(map, extent = "device", ylab = "lat", xlab = "lon") + 
  geom_segment(aes(y = geo$lon, x = geo$lat, yend = geo$lonend, xend = geo$latend))
```

Do you have any suggestions for what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your segment is not being plotted because you confused latitude and longitude, x corresponds to longitude, y to latitude. In addition, you should use `data = geo` and remove `geo$` from `aes()`

```
ggmap(map, extent = "device", ylab = "lat", xlab = "lon") + 
  geom_segment(data = geo, aes(y = lat, x = lon, yend = latend, xend = lonend))
```

Also, in order to display an arrow just add `arrow = arrow()` to `geom_segment`:

```
ggmap(map, extent = "device", ylab = "lat", xlab = "lon") + 
  geom_segment(data = geo, aes(y = lat, x = lon, yend = latend, xend = lonend),
               arrow = arrow())
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding: `eom_segment(data = geo, arrow(y = lat, x = lon, yend = latend, xend = lonend)) `

but it seems its not working :(

Comment: @MikeR please see my edited answer, it should be clear now :)

Comment: thanks for that! Now im getting an arrow which is the most important part. 

What do I do if i want an arrow to go from the first destination to another destination?

Lets say i add the following data to my geo dataset:
`secondrow=c(11.10557,60.18959,12.10557,62.18959,999)
geo <- rbind(geo,secondrow)`

Seems like it is not creating an additional arrow by default - what would i need to change in the geom_segment?

Comment: @MikeR the coordinates are outside the plot limits, thus the second arrow does not show. Change the `zoom` to 4 and you'll see it.

Comment: @MikeR glad I could help, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the check mark :)

Comment: sorry, still a bit new to stackoverflow